# How to do position by position sorting in an array of array of numbers using Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of strings that I have to sort:

```
['1.2.3', '1.5.2', '1.23', '1.20.31']
```

Is it possible to sort the array so that after you split a string by the dot like `1.2.3` into `['1','2', '3']` we do position by position comparison with another array (like Python tuple comparison)?

Expected result

```
['1.2.3', '1.5.2' '1.20.31', '1.23']
```

I know it can be doen using native JavaScript `.sort` with comparison function taking 2 objects, but I can't use the JS sort because I can't modify the original array. Is it possible using Lodash's **`_.sortBy`** which expects you to give a key function?

Comment: would you be opposed to making a copy of the original array by using `Array.slice()` ?

Comment: your expected result does not match your requirement. if separated by dots, the `'1.5.2'` should be sorted before `'1.20.31'`, hence `5 < 20`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with `Vanilla.js`:

```js
var data = ['1.2.3', '1.5.2', '1.23', '1.20.31'];

function customSort(d) {
    return d.map(function (a) {
        return a.split('.').map(Number);
    }).sort(function (a, b) {
        var l = 0, m = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
        while (l < m && a[l] === b[l]) {
            l++;
        }
        return l === m ? a.length - b.length : a[l] - b[l];
    }).map(function (a) {
        return a.join('.');
    });
}

document.write('<pre>sorted array ' + JSON.stringify(customSort(data), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>original array ' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

ES5 + Lodash

```
var data = ['1.2.3', '1.5.2', '1.23', '1.20.31'];
var sortedData = _.sortBy(data, function(x){ return
                   x.split('.')
                    .map(function(i){ return 
                       _.padLeft(i, 5, '0'); })
                    .join('');
                 }));
```

ES6 + Lodash

```
var data = ['1.2.3', '1.5.2', '1.23', '1.20.31'];
var sorteddData = _.sortBy(data, x =>
                    x.split('.')
                     .map(i => _.padLeft(i, 5, '0'))
                     .join('')
                    );
```

Comment: I don't think this works because it returns `["1.2.3", "1.20.31", "1.23", "1.5.2"]` but `1.5.2` should come before `1.20.31` since `5` < `20`

Comment: @JaeWie, you need numeric comparision, that will take little bit more code, I have updated code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sortByAll()](https://lodash.com/docs#sortByAll) to do complex sorting like this:

```
var arr = ['1.2.3', '1.5.2', '1.23', '1.20.31', '1.20.29'];

function splitNumber(index, str) {
    return parseInt(_.get(str.split('.'), index, 0));
}

_.sortByAll(
    arr,
    _.partial(splitNumber, 0),
    _.partial(splitNumber, 1),
    _.partial(splitNumber, 2)
);
// → ["1.2.3", "1.5.2", "1.20.29", "1.20.31", "1.23"]
```

The `splitNumber()` function gets the item from a string we want to sort by, as an integer. Then we use [partial()](https://lodash.com/docs#partial) to create the 3 iteratees for `sortByAll()`.